# Apache tomcat deployment

Tags: apache, tomcat, war, web-deployment

I have a war file which is a simple dynamic web application where I will call a JSP file which calls a Java file and does some stuff. There is no servlet programming involved.

I deployed the war file in the webapps folder of the tomcat folder.

I restarted the server, the application is extracted and when i call the jsp file like below it is working like a charm.

```
localhost:8080/Login/login.jsp
```

But i want to create a directory structure in the webapps folder and place the war file in it and access it as follows

the directory structure is

```
<tom cat folder>webapps/myapp/mylogin/<my war file>
```

what i did was copied the extracted war file from the webapps folder and pasted it in the above directory structure

When i accessed it like below it is throwing error

```
localhost:8080/myapp/mylogin/Login/login.jsp
```

Please let me know how to host my war file with directory structure in webapps folder.

Hope i was clear in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to make a mapping in the server.xml file.

```
  <Host name="showcase.com"  appBase="webapps/myapp/mylogin/"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
  </Host>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work. What is the error in the log files (access log file, stdout/stderr) and on the screen ?